# evaluation of the definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Actually i am finding the arc length of curve 
$24xy = y^4 + 48$ from $y = 2$ to $y = 4$
i have found the derivative with respect to $y$ and that is $$\frac{y^2}6 -\frac{x}y$$
by putting this derivative in the arc length formula i get the following

$$\int_2^4 \sqrt{1+ \left(\frac{y^2}6 -\frac{x}y\right)^2}$$

I solve this definite integral by substitution but i am failed please help me, give me some hints. I will be thankful.

Comment: how you got this result x(y)= y^3/24 + 2/y show me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $$24xy=y^{4}+48$$ we find $$x=\frac{1}{24}\frac{y^{4}+48}{y}.$$ Thus
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}=\frac{1}{8}\frac{y^{4}-16}{y^{2}}.
$$

The length of the curve is 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
L &=&\int_{2}^{4}\sqrt{1+\left( \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}\right) ^{2}}\mathrm{d}y=\int_{2}^{4}
\sqrt{1+\left( \frac{1}{8}\frac{y^{4}-16}{y^{2}}\right) ^{2}}\mathrm{d}y 
&=&\dots\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: @Zia ur Rahman: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

HINT It might be easier to think of $x$ as a function of $y$: $$x = \frac{y^4}{24y} + \frac{48}{24y} = \ldots (\text{simplify}),$$
where $y$ ranges from $2$ to $4$. I presume you know how to calculate the arclength when the curve is given in this form.

Comment: how you did that, x(y)=y^3/24 + 2/y

Comment: @Zia The given equation is $24 y x = blah$. So just divide the whole thing by $24y$. Note: By $x(y)$, I mean: $x$ as a function of $y$; it does not mean $x$ multiplied by $y$.

Comment: ok now i try to solve this whole question thank you i will contact you if i could not just after five minutes ok?

Comment: @Zia Sure. You can can post your progress either in the question itself or in the comments.

Comment: derivative with respect to y of this function of x comes out y^2/8 - 2/y^2 now if we put this into the definite integral and suppose it u then we again need to take the derivative with respect to y that comes out du/dy = y/4 +4/y^3 now what i do?

Comment: I have no idea what $u$ is, and why you are differentiating that w.r.t. $y$. You only need to integrate $(1+(dx/dy)^2)^{1/2}$ w.r.t. $y$ between the given limits. Is this where you are stuck?